# System.DmlException: Insert failed. first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [File Name, Body]: [File Name, Body]

Tags: visualforce, attachment

page:

```
    <apex:page StandardController="TicketIntakeform__c" extensions="forAttachmentsCls">
    <apex:form>
    <br/><br/>
  <apex:panelGrid columns="1" style="display: table; width: 100%">
    <apex:outputPanel id="panel1" style="text-align: center; display: block">
      <apex:outputLabel ><b>Case Creation For Other System</b></apex:outputLabel><br/>
      <apex:selectList id="OptionsforOtherSys" value="{!selectedValue}" size="1" required="TRUE" multiselect="FALSE">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!OtherSystemOptions}"/>
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onChangeFnCall}"  rerender="pc"/>
      </apex:selectList>
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:panelGrid>
  <apex:outputPanel id="pc">
   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!punchCorrPgRendered}">
    <div>
      <c:forAttachmentsComp svalue="{!selectedValue}"/>
    </div>
  </apex:outputPanel>

  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Component:

```
       <apex:outputLabel escape="false" value="<b>Attachment</b>" for="attachId"/> 
       <apex:inputfile size="35" id="attachId"  value="{!file.body}" fileName="{!file.name}"/>
      <apex:commandButton styleClass="TabSpace" action="{!save}" value="Save" />
    </apex:component>
```

Class:

```
public class forAttachmentsCls{
    public String selectedValue{get;set;}
    public String valueSelected{get;set;}
    public Attachment file{set;get;}
    public List<SelectOption> otherSystemOptions;
    public boolean punchCorrPgRendered {get;set;}


    public forAttachmentsCls(){
        file = new Attachment();
    }
     public forAttachmentsCls(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
      otherSystemOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    }


     public List<SelectOption> getOtherSystemOptions() {
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult description = TicketIntakeform__c.case_creation_for_other_Systems__c.getDescribe();
      for (Schema.Picklistentry pl : description.getPicklistValues())
      {
          otherSystemOptions.add(new SelectOption(pl.getValue(),pl.getLabel()));
      }
      return otherSystemOptions;
    }
    public void onChangeFnCall(){
       if(selectedValue=='Historical punch Correction'){
           punchCorrPgRendered = TRUE;
       }
       else if(selectedValue=='Instant Issue'){
           //pageBlock2Rendered = TRUE;
           //count++;
       }
    }


    public PageReference save(){

        TicketIntakeform__c acc = new TicketIntakeform__c();
        acc.name = 'test Attachment1';
        Insert acc;
        system.debug(file.Name);
        System.debug(acc.id);
        Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = acc.Id, name = file.Name, body=file.body) ;
        Insert a;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component code should be like this.

```
<apex:component controller="forAttachmentsCls" allowDML="true"> 
   <apex:form>
      <apex:outputLabel escape="false" value="<b>Attachment</b>" for="attachId"/> 
      <apex:inputfile id="attachId" value="{!file.body}" fileName="{!file.name}"/> 
      <apex:commandButton styleClass="TabSpace" action="{!save}" value="Save"/> 
   </apex:form>  
</apex:component>
```