# picklist was are doubled after form is submitted

Tags: visualforce, picklist

[image]

[enter link description here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223297/system-dmlexception-insert-failed-first-error-required-field-missing-require)

Same code pasted here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Have to initialize your picklist selectoption inside the method so everytime you rerender the page, it will not add more values to it.

It will always initialize and then add the values to select option

```
public List<SelectOption> getOtherSystemOptions() {
      otherSystemOptions = new List<SelectOption>(); // here you have initialize
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult description = TicketIntakeform__c.case_creation_for_other_Systems__c.getDescribe();
      for (Schema.Picklistentry pl : description.getPicklistValues())
      {
          otherSystemOptions.add(new SelectOption(pl.getValue(),pl.getLabel()));
      }
      return otherSystemOptions;
    }
```